# Leaflet popups only displays columns where cell information NOT NULL?

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, popup, esri-leaflet

I've got the following map on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/4/).

The popup information comes from an Arcgis Server with 23 columns. When you click around the markers you can see that most of the popup information are not filled.

How could I add code to display only info where the info is NOT NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/6/). I hope it is what you need.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But the code has a little bug. In my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/8/) I am working with aliases to rename the real column names. E.g. take the playground you can see when you start the map and look at the popup. It has **In Grünanlage/Park:** x . Now looking at your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/9/) and at the same playground it hides the info. I guess it's because you used my aliases in **var spielangebote**. Would you mind to have a look again at the code?

Comment: You can use a two dimensional array or a json with the aliases and the real column names. I updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/10/) and now you can get all info in the popup.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is diplayed as wanted!